# Pair with noinputnooutput remote bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, pairing

I want to pair my PC with a remote bluetooth device whose IO capacity is set as "noinputnooutput" as this device has neither keyboard nor display but my PC always generates a pin code to support from the remote device or asks me to put the pin code of the remote device which is not exist. Now I want to make this pair without any pin code. Is there any configuration in my PC to do that?

I'm trying from Ubuntu 17.10 also I tried it from windows machine

Comment: Your device IO capability may not be NoInputNoOutput. Some bluetooth product vendors (ex: handsfree devices), use DisplayOnly as IO capability and uses a hardcoded pin inside. That means though the product doesn't have any input or output capabilities they still ask for pin because they are programmed to act as display device.

Comment: If you are using latest bluetooth stack on your Ubuntu, run btmon tool and capture logs to confirm the IO capabilities of your remote bluetooth device. On old Linux bluetooth stack you can use hcidump for capturing logs.

Comment: No, the vendor indicates that the device only supports NoInputNoOutput IO capacity